# HttpContext.Response.Redirect .NET Core returns 404

Tags: c#, .net, angular, cookies

I'm using .Net Core Api as back-end, and Angular 8 as front-end. I need to implement redirect to front-end login page when user sends request to back-end API without cookie (using  context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect and Authorize attribute). But after redirect my front-end returns 404.

My .net Core code:
[image: code]
And result:

[image: result]

Otherwise, when i call this address from browser it works:

[image: result]

Comment: Do you have any route config for login ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the redirect, if it gets there verify that baseurl is defined. As a test hardwire the redirect path in the redirect, if that works check out your config file for proper values.

Comment: Would you please show us the frontend code that is supposed to handle the response(redirect from the server), I am guessing you are expecting anything that happened at backend(response or redirect) to be sent back to the frontend, maybe if we see the frontend part we'll be able to help